# How to color by sub-groups with plotweb in bipartite?

Tags: r, bipartite

I'm using plotweb in bipartite to plot plant-pollinator networks and would really like to be able to color the boxes of insects by order. I have not been able to find or figure out an easy way to do this. And doing it manually (listing a color for each individual box) is even more annoying than expected because the function changes the order of the boxes to minimize crossing-over. Our data is a series of insects (in this format: Hymenoptera_Megachilidae_Megachile_policaris) and plants (in this format: Ratibida columnifera) from different Plots all within the object Web (made using frame2webs).

I found that using ifelse and the exact label name would let me select specific boxes to color and if I nested them I could do multiple and it worked.

`` plotweb(Web$`Plot`,col.high=ifelse(colnames(Web$`Plot`)== "Hymenoptera_Megachilidae_Megachile_policaris","red4", ifelse(colnames(Web$`Plot`)== "Hymenoptera_Halictidae_Lasioglossum_bruneri","red4","grey80"))) ``

I tried to see if I could set a color to all boxes with labels starting with "Hymenoptera" that way I'd only have to do a line per order. But for some reason it didn't apply the color to the right boxes (it was a seemly random selection of which ones were and weren't colored red.

`` plotweb(Web$`Plot`,col.high=ifelse(Web$'Plot'== grepl('^Hymenoptera', Web$`Plot`),"red4","grey80")) ``

So unfortunately, this definitely didn't work. The same assortment as the entry above were colored and that was it. Only red and grey even though there *were* representatives from each order

`` plotweb(Web$`Plot`,col.high=ifelse(Web$`Crow Gas`== grepl('^Hymenoptera', Web$`Plot`),"red4",ifelse(Web$`Plot`== grepl('^Coleoptera', Web$`Plot`),"cyan4", ifelse(Web$`Plot`== grepl('^Diptera', Web$`Crow Gas`),"green","grey80")))) ``

At this point I know it would work, but I don't want to end up with an ifelse for every single species, manually making each the color that corresponds to its order. Even being able to concatenate or use an "or" (I've tried both and neither worked) that lets me list several species per color so I only have 3 ifelses (even if they are ridiculously long) would be nice. But *preferably* I'd like something as I had attempted before using substrings of the insect labels so the code could easily be applied to different plots that have different set of species so I don't have to make up a whole list of every species any time I do a different plot.